# Why running execFile method does not show the expected text in console from its callback?

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am using gulp start task to run my indx.coffee file with nodemon as bellow:

```js
  1 var gulp = require('gulp');
  2 var execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
  3 
  4 gulp.task("start", function(cb) {
  5   execFile('nodemon', ['src/index.coffee'], function(err, stdo, stde) {
  6     if(err)
  7       return cb(err);
  8     else
  9       console.log('Server started');
 10   });
 11 });
```

But after running `gulp start` from command line It doesn't write `Server started` to console.
Can anybody help?